# Table of employee sick leave in Excel by using VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, unpivot

I want to write code by using macro VBA which calculate the number of rows depend on the different between the leave date and to the end date of leave date , then change the row values to start from the first date of month to the end.

example:

```
name          start_leave_date    end_ leave_date 
customer_1    20/3/2020           7/6/2020
customer_2    12/1/2020           15/3/2020
```

so the result should looks like this

```
name        start_leave_date     end_leave_date 
customer_1  20/3/2020            31/3/2020
customer_1  01/4/2020            30/4/2020
customer_1  01/5/2020            31/5/2020
customer_1  01/6/2020            07/6/2020
customer_2  12/1/2020            31/1/2020
customer_2  01/2/2020            28/2/2020
customer_2  12/3/2020            31/3/2020
```

so there is 5 rows for customers 1 because there is different of 5 months between the start and the end of leave date

so can some one help me to know what i need to add in my code to show this output , thank you

[image]

my code and my result but it need to modify to get the output which i need

1. input

[image: input of excel]

2. output
   [image: output of the code]
3. my VBA code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim numberOfCopies As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
'Dim Lastrowa As Long


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("info").Columns("E").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("info").Columns("D").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("info").Columns("F").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new").Columns("E").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new").Columns("D").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new").Columns("F").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Set rng = Range("A2", Range("J1").End(xlDown))

For Each r In rng.Rows
    '## Get the number of months
    numberOfCopies = r.Cells(1, 11).Value
  
     If numberOfCopies > 0 Then
  
        '## Add to a new sheet
        With Sheets("new")
            '## copy the row and paste repeatedly in this loop
            For n = 1 To numberOfCopies
               lastRow = Sheets("new").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
                
                r.Copy
                '.Range ("A" & n)
                 Sheets("new").Range("A" & lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Next
            
        End With
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unpivot Monthly

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- If you don't want to copy the last column you can define the `Source Range` like this:

  ```
  Dim srg As Range
  With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst).CurrentRegion
      Set srg = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1)
  End With
  ```

  Use `- 2` if you don't want the last two columns.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub unpivotMonthly()
    
    ' Define Constants.
    Const sName As String = "info"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    Const dName As String = "new"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    Const cStart As Long = 5
    Const cEnd As Long = 6

    ' Define Workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst).CurrentRegion
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(Data, 1) ' Source Rows Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2) ' Columns Count
    
    ' Define Months Array.
    Dim mData As Variant: ReDim mData(2 To srCount)
    Dim rrCount As Long: rrCount = 1 ' Result Array Rows Count - 1 for headers
    Dim mDiff As Long ' Current Months Between First and Last (incl.)
    Dim i As Long ' Data (Source) Array Rows Counter
    
    ' Calculate Result Array Rows Count and populate Months Array.
    For i = 2 To srCount
        mDiff = DateDiff("M", Data(i, cStart), Data(i, cEnd)) + 1
        mData(i) = mDiff
        rrCount = rrCount + mDiff
    Next i
    
    ' Define Result Array.
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To rrCount, 1 To cCount)
    Dim k As Long: k = 1 ' Result Array Rows Counter - 1 for headers
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim j As Long ' Data and Result Array Columns Counter
    Dim m As Long ' Months Counter
    
    ' Write headers.
    For j = 1 To cCount
        Result(1, j) = Data(1, j)
    Next j
    
    ' Write 'body'.
    For i = 2 To srCount
        For m = 1 To mData(i)
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To cCount
                Select Case j
                Case cStart
                    If mData(i) = 1 Then
                        Result(k, j) = Data(i, j)
                        Result(k, cEnd) = Data(i, cEnd)
                    Else
                        If m = 1 Then
                            Result(k, j) = Data(i, j)
                            Result(k, cEnd) = dateLastInMonth(Data(i, j))
                        Else
                            If m = mData(i) Then
                                Result(k, j) = dateFirstInMonth(Data(i, cEnd))
                                Result(k, cEnd) = Data(i, cEnd)
                            Else
                                Result(k, j) = Result(k - 1, cEnd) + 1
                                Result(k, cEnd) = dateLastInMonth(Result(k, j))
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Case Is <> cEnd
                    Result(k, j) = Data(i, j)
                End Select
            Next j
        Next m
    Next i
    
    ' Write result.
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst).Resize(, cCount)
        .Resize(k).Value = Result
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - k + 1).Offset(k).ClearContents
    End With
    
End Sub

Function dateFirstInMonth( _
    ByVal d As Date) _
As Date
    dateFirstInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
End Function

Function dateLastInMonth( _
    ByVal d As Date) _
As Date
    If Month(d) = 12 Then
        dateLastInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), 12, 31)
    Else
        dateLastInMonth = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) + 1, 1) - 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: what is sFirst and dFirst ? sorry i'm still new in macro. because it show constant error  @VBasic2008

Comment: You don't have to address me when in my comments section. `sFirst` is the range address of the first cell of your data in the `Source Worksheet`, worksheet `info` in this case, and `A1` according to your screenshot. Similarly for `dFirst`, it is the range address of the first cell where you want to copy the resulting data (worksheet `new`). There is no (to me) known reason for this to happen. When this happens to me, I usually create a new workbook and copy the data to it.

Comment: It should work since I tested it a lot. Let me know if your table doesn't start in `A1`, then you have to define the `Source Range` differently. For the `Destination` you can choose any cell, like `B2`, `C3`...  I'm talking here about the whole range, including headers. Also, check if the worksheet names are correct. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vl_aNpxtuxyi213Ux4B3kiiZJf5Jt7y3/view?usp=sharing) to my file on `Google Drive`. You have to download it to test it. There is a down arrow on the top-right.

Comment: Thank you, i have another question plz, how i can count the duration column which represent the number of days of each row in the other sheet (new ) after counting the rows

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim sDAy As Date, eDay As Date
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    Dim j As Integer, c As Integer, k As Integer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1) 'set input Sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2) 'set ouput Sheet
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    
    ReDim vR(1 To 11, 1 To r * 20)
    For i = 2 To r
        sDAy = getDay(vDB(i, 5)) '<~~if Leave from is not text -> vDB(i,5)
        eDay = getDay(vDB(i, 6)) '<~~if Leave to is not text -> vDB(i,6)
        c = DateDiff("m", sDAy, eDay)
        For j = 0 To c
            n = n + 1
            Select Case c
            Case 0
                vR(5, n) = sDAy
                vR(6, n) = eDay
            Case Else
                If j = c Then
                    vR(5, n) = DateSerial(Year(sDAy), Month(sDAy) + j, 1)
                    vR(6, n) = eDay
                ElseIf j = 0 Then
                    vR(5, n) = sDAy
                    vR(6, n) = DateSerial(Year(sDAy), Month(sDAy) + j + 1, 0)
                Else
                    vR(5, n) = DateSerial(Year(sDAy), Month(sDAy) + j, 1)
                    vR(6, n) = DateSerial(Year(sDAy), Month(sDAy) + j + 1, 0)
                End If
            End Select
            For k = 1 To 11
                If k < 5 Or k > 6 Then
                    vR(k, n) = vDB(i, k)
                    If k = 4 Then
                        vR(k, n) = getDay(vDB(i, k)) 'if [Star work date]is not text then remove this line
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 11, 1 To n)
    With toWs
        .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents
        .Range("a2").Resize(n, 11) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
        .Range("d:f").NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
Function getDay(v As Variant)
    Dim vS
    vS = Split(v, "/")
    
    getDay = DateSerial(vS(2), vS(1), vS(0))
    
End Function
```

Comment: thanks , how i can count the duration column which represent the number of days of each row in the other sheet (new ) after counting the row